# Annoying popup about cookies

Tags: feature-request

Recently, every time I visit Mathoverflow, I get a popup asking me to allow cookies. I have nothing against this in principle, but might there be a way that lets me respond and be done with it instead of having this pop up every time?

Comment: And it's only MathOverflow, not other stacks.

Comment: I'm getting it on all SE sites. I can block it on MO by adding mathoverflow.net##.js-consent-banner.r16.l16.b16.bar-lg.fc-white.bg-black-750.p32.sm\:w-auto.ws4.z-nav-fixed.ps-fixed.ff-sans to my uBlock Origin filter list, but I don't know a solution that works uniformly across SE sites.

Comment: This is due to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359358. There are several reports of users for whom the dialog does not remember the settings or otherwise misbehaves, such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359691. It seems one cause might be that the browser blocks third-party cookies for security reasons (which is a good thing to do; IOW, the design with off-sourcing the dialog to a third party is a stupid idea). Anyway, based on the comments, the only solution that works now seems to be to kill the dialog with an ad blocker.

Comment: I got the dialog twice, and then never again.  When you agree, it is not supposed to return next time.  But (as noted in the question) that does not always work.

Answer (score -1):

If You are using Chrome there is a really good extension called Cookie Notice Blocker. It works for most sites so it probably also works on mathoverflow.