# Mystery popup window

Tags: discussion, support, user-interface

Last week or so, when I get into an SE site (MO in particular), a popup window appears in the lower left corner for few milliseconds. Some kind of clickable button there, with not enough time for me to figure out what it is. On different SE sites it is different but looks similar in design.

Do others encounter this too? Does anybody know what is it and how to get rid of it?

Strictly speaking this belongs to the whole SE meta, please migrate it if it is off-topic here.

Comment: This is most likely not it, but just to eliminate it, I'll ask anyway. The window asking to accept cookies is in the bottom left corner. (But I never saw it disappear immediately, as you describe.) You can find screenshot in many places: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=cookie+site:meta.stackexchange.com - such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359358, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362694, https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362091,  There is also a post on this meta - but without a screenshot: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4954

Comment: Although I see this bug report which might look a bit similar to yours: [Cookie dialog popup flashes for a moment even when I've already accepted all cookies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362876). However, it is marked as ([meta-tag:status-norepro]).

Comment: Do you have any browser add-ons, does it happen across browsers, across computers? Which browser, which operating system? What was the phase of the moon when you first noticed the symptoms? Were you recently stung by Africanized honey bees? Most of these questions should be answered already when submitting a bug report.

Comment: Yes it was the cookie business, it showed up after I switched off my adblocker. Thanks Martin and Asaf for pointing me in the right direction. Maybe you can also advise what to do with this question? Provide an answer, mark it as duplicate, migrate to SE meta, or just delete it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I don't see closing as a duplicate as an option - we would need a duplicate target *here on MathOverflow Meta* and I do not see such a post. If you think that it might help somebody else who runs into the same problem, then it seems quite reasonable to write an answer (with an explanation what was actually the problem and how it can be solved). But it's your question - so it's your call. (Or you might simply wait to see whether some MO users chime in to respond to your most recent comment.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak OK, I will wait a couple of days then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Martin Sleziak correctly suggested, it turned out to be the cookie acceptance notification: an ad blocker forced it to close immediately.